# Running more stable in wintery conditions than walking

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, everyday-life, ice

Maybe this is just a me-thing but I found when I run in snowy conditions I do not slip or fall unless I hit an unknown patch of ice. However, when I walk, I'm more likely to slip in general. Looking for answers on this I don't see any explanation come up for this phenomena.

Is there something involving running that makes it more stable? Is it just me?

Comment: It is hard to imagine that, under all conditions, having one foot at a time in contact with the ground and forward momentum results in fewer slips/falls than often having two feet on the ground and less forward momentum. Or shuffling and keeping two feet in contact.

Comment: @JonCuster that's what I'd think, I've just walked and ran in snow a number of times and felt very stable running and less so walking. I did sprints on a snow covered track yesterday and it was fine. Hence the question, it's strange. If 5 other runners respond and say "he's nuts, it's worse" we can just say I'm an outlier.

Comment: When you have two feet on the ground, you only have 50% of your weight on each point of contact; each point has less forwards momentum than when running. Perhaps these differences lead to less stability, or more 'vulnerability' to, and more likelyhood of, small perturbations (slips) having larger effects?

Answer (score 2):

Running on flat slippery surfaces seems to be more stable than walking for some birds. Faster gaits may also be more stable for humans, but the increased stability from speed can be more than offset from decreased stability from longer stride lengths.

Slips tend to happen when a leg is extended too far in front of your base-of-support (i.e. your foot) so it is no longer under your centre-of-mass. My understanding of the research is that when running, your centre-of-mass is more likely to keep moving forward over your foot, restoring stability. This increase in stability can be negated, however, if when running you extend your leg out farther in front, so the initial contact is even farther out from under your body.

In ["Slipping, sliding and stability: locomotor strategies for overcoming low-friction surfaces"](https://doi.org/10.1242/jeb.051136), researchers reported that [helmeted guineafowl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmeted_guineafowl) were less likely to fall when running at higher speeds. (Note: "Helmeted" does not mean they were fitted with protective headgear; it is just part of their species name.) The birds were more likely to slip if their limb contact angle with the ground was less than 70°. (A limb contact angle of 90° corresponds to having their centre-of-mass directly over their foot that was in contact with the ground.) When moving faster than 3 m/s, however, they were much less likely to slip even when their limb contact angles were less than 70°.

This seems consistent with earlier studies on walking (not running) humans. According to ["Influence of gait speed on stability: recovery from anterior slips and compensatory stepping"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gaitpost.2004.01.008), walking humans are more likely to fall over backwards when they hit a slippery patch while walking at slower speeds. This is counter-intuitive, since the natural inclination of elderly adults is to walk more slowly when it is slippery.
A [later paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gaitpost.2010.06.013), however, reported that although a slower gait does lead to more instability and falls, this can be offset by reducing step length.

So it is plausible, but far from certain, that you may be more stable running than walking in snowy conditions, especially if you consciously or unconsciously reduce your stride length.
Note that none of this research applies to walking or running on the uneven ice produced by erratically compacted snow that is common on many northern sidewalks and streets in winter.  If your foot starts to slide sideways off an icy bump, it not clear if your forward momentum will be any help in avoiding a fall.

Comment: That is a fantastic answer and extremely helpful. Also makes sense! I'll accept it tomorrow so as to not discourage other answers.